# Strongloop API query by base model

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

We have multiple models with a common base model. E.g. `creature` as a base, and `animal` and `human` as sub models, inheriting from `creature`.

Is there a ready-to-use method to query for all `creature`s (be it `human` or `animal`) with one API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with the built-in methods.

Models in loopback you should not be viewed as object, they are not made for OOP.

They do define basic behavior which you can extend later on using custom config & code, but that's it, there is no way to query the parent model. The base model is merely a template for the extending model.

Instead, use the [relation system](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Creating+model+relations) to define relationship between models. But in your case, you want a ready-to-go method with a single API call, so that means you will need a single Model to host all instances to be queried.

I would do the following:

- `Creature` extends `PersistedModel`

And add a property `type` of type string. Give it `human` for humans, `animal` for animals, etc.

Then, you can [get all instances](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Querying+data)[ with a GET request

```
GET /creatures?filter[where][and][0][type]=human&filter[where][and][1][type]=animal
```

Also see [where](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Where+filter) filter